# How can I able to display todays working hour in a different colour in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

My script for the same to display is

```
const workHour = "Monday :9:00AM to 5:00PM,Thuesday :9:00AM to 5:00PM,Wednesday :9:00AM to 5:00PM,Tuesday : 9:00AM to 5:00PM,Friday :9:00AM to 5:00PM,Saturday :9:00AM to 5:00PM,Sunday :9:00AM to 5:00PM".split(',').map((val) => { 
  const obj = val.split(':');
  const time = val.replace(`${obj[0]}:`, '');
  return {
    day: obj[0],
    time,
  }
});
console.log(workHour);
```

HTML CODE TO DISPLAY THE VALUES ARE

```
   <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="(item,key) in data.workHr" :key="key">{{item.day}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(item,key) in data.workHr" :key="key">{{item.time}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

By this, I am able to display the date as well as working hours. I need to change colour of todays working hours and automatically update for tomorrow? Can anyone please help to solve the problem?

Comment: This isn't a problem but a task. May you add the _actual_ issue you're facing?

Comment: is you want to change the colour according to the changes in date? Is it required? I today is monday you need to highlight and likewise you need to highlight tuesday tomorrow right?

Comment: yes sir,, i need the same @Wanderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following codes

> With if

```
 <td v-for="(item,key) in workHr" :key="key">
    <span v-if="new Date().getDay()-1==key" class="today">{{item.time}}</span>
    <span v-else-if="new Date().getDay()==key" class="tomorrow">{{item.time}}</span>
    <span v-else >{{item.time}}</span>
 </td>
```

> With class object

```
<span :class="{'tomorrow':new Date().getDay()==key,'today':new Date().getDay()-1==key}">{{item.time}}</span>
```

If condition demo:https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/76096/

Class object demo:https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/77860/